# Como manipular uma TD usando Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um valor em um TD e preciso recuperar ele, é um calendario e cada data que eu clico do calentario existe uma classe diferente em cada data, preciso que, quando eu clique nessa data eu consiga recuperar o dia mes e ano do dia que eu cliquei, eu tenho o seguinte retorno executando esse código.

resumindo preciso recuperar essa data que esta aparecendo no console.

```
var dateSelectClick = $(target); console.log(dateSelectClick);
```

segue uma print com o retorno do console.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Detalhe mais sua pergunta, informe quais plugins você está usando. Imagino que você esteja usando Moment.js, se for então você recupera com dateSelectClick.get(0).date.format()

Comment: Esse calendário é um datepicker ou html simples? Podes dar um exemplo do html ou indicar qual o datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Tente percorrer o objeto

```
var objData = $(target);
var dateSelect = "";

$('elemento').click(function(){

 $.each(objData,function(i,e){
    dateSelect = e.data._i; //copia o valor da data para variavel dateSelect
  });

});
```